# How get Current-User At Asp.net-Core at cross platform react redux?

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux, asp.net-core-identity

Hello  have got one `ReportController` (without its view) for creating saving updating one table with datas.
I use react redux with fetch to run the actions of this controller.
For authentication I am using Asp.net Core Identity. And the authentication take place on asp.net, not on react-redux. I can get current user at manage and account controller using HttpContext. But when I try use `HttpContext` to get current user at my `ReportController` while creating new data I get `null` with `HttpContext`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that i wasn't sending the cookies with my fetch.

```
credentials: 'same-origin'
```